# How can I remove all non numeric digits from text field onblur?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove all non numeric digits from text field with onblur=?
need to take out () and - from phone number before submit.

Comment: Well, `blur` is the event you should attach an `eventListener` to, `value` is the property of the `HTMLElement` you should look at, and you should use a Regular Expression to glean all numbers from the `value`.  Start there and edit your question after you have something to work with.  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @zero298 that's a little harsh. I'm all for not supporting people who want their work done for them but OP is clearly just asking for help on the replacement part, I'm sure they can figure out the rest on their own. no need to downvote

Comment: @Pabs123 Then the poster should post what they have attempted already and be more explicit in where they are running into trouble.  The question shows no attempt so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cleanInput(string){
   return string.replace(/\D/g,'');
}
```

That will return a string with no non-numeric characters, just set the input's value to the result